# Building up a LINQ query based on bools

Tags: c#, .net, linq

(The title for this question isn't the best, but I'm unsure how else to word it!)

I'm working on a search form which contains a checklist of values. Basically, a checked item means 'include this type in the search'. Something like this:

```
Search for item: __________
Search in:
      [ ] Fresh Foods
      [ ] Frozen Foods
      [ ] Beverages
      [ ] Deli Counter
```

I have an object to represent this search:

```
class FoodSearchCriteria{
    public string SearchString {get;set;}
    public bool SearchFreshFoods {get;set;}
    public bool SearchFrozenFoods {get;set;}
    public bool SearchBeverages {get;set;}
    public bool SearchDeliCounter {get;set;}
}
```

The only way I can think of doing this atm is like this:

```
public IList<FoodItem> FindFoodItems(FoodSearchCriteria criteria)
// in reality, this is a fuzzy search not an exact match
var matches = _DB.FoodItems.Where(x => x.FoodTitle == SearchString);

var inCategories = new List<FoodItem>();

if (criteria.SearchFreshFoods)
   inCategories.Add(matches.Where(x => x.Type == 'Fresh Foods'));
if (criteria.SearchFrozenFoods)
   inCategories.Add(matches.Where(x => x.Type == 'Frozen Foods'));
//etc etc

return inCategories;
}
```

This feels like a code smell to me, what would be a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
List<string> types = new List<string>();

if (criteria.SearchFreshFoods) { types.Add("Fresh Foods"); }
if (criteria.SearchFrozenFoods) { types.Add("Frozen Foods"); }
if (criteria.SearchBeverages) { types.Add("Beverages"); }
if (criteria.SearchDeliCounter) { types.Add("Deli Counter"); }

return _DB.FoodItems.Where(x => x.FoodTitle == SearchString &&
                                types.Contains(x.Type));
```

That means just one SQL query, which is handy.

You could certainly refactor the FoodSearchCriteria type to make it easier to build the list though...

Comment: Feel free to elaborate on what refactoring you have in mind :)

Comment: Not sure off-hand... but at the very least it would make sense to put the code to build the list *into* that class.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
PredicateBuilder predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<FoodItem>();
if (criteria.SearchFreshFoods)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Type == 'Fresh Foods');
}
if (criteria.SearchFrozenFoods)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Type == 'Frozen Foods'));
}
...

_DB.FoodItems.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Looks incompleet. pb == predicate?

Answer (score 0):

I have no time to review but this could be an untested solution.

```
class SearchItem
{
   string Name {get; set;}
   bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}

class FoodSearchCriteria
{
   String searchText {get; set;}
   IList<SearchItem> SearchItems{ get; }
}

public IList<FoodItem> FindFoodItems(FoodSearchCriteria criteria)
// in reality, this is a fuzzy search not an exact match
var matches = _DB.FoodItems.Where(x => x.FoodTitle == criteria.SearchText && 
                                      criteria.SearchItems.Where(si => si.IsSelected).Contains(i => i.Name == x.Type));

return mathces;
}
```